# Getting another controllers instance class

Tags: iphone, class, get, instance

I have learned how to pass and instance of a class to another class, but I have yet to understand how to do it the other way arround.

Example:

Lets say that we are in rootViewController and in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath we pass the instance of playlist to someviewcontroller like this:

```
SomeViewController *someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

playlist = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
someViewController.playlist = playlist;
```

Now this works perfectly for passing the class instance forward, but lets instead say that Im in the someViewController and want rootViewController playlist.

How would I go about achieving this using a similar technique? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you want to pass the someViewController playlist to the rootViewController or just access the rootViewController playlist from someViewController?

Comment: @TompaLompa In this example Im passing it to someviewcontroller. I instead want to acess someviewcontrollers playlist.

Comment: I would implement a delegate for someViewController like Steve Moser suggested. And then let rootViewController implement the protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the delegation pattern: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Also check out Apple's CoreDataRecipes sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

You can see in the sample code that the RecipeListTableViewController is a delegate of the RecipeAddViewController so that when the RecipeAddViewController is done RecipeListTableViewController can show the recipe in the RecipeDetailViewController.

Delegation also helps with your object graph because the reference to the delegate is a weak link which means that it won't retain your delegate. So by using the delegation pattern you ensure that you don't create any retain cycles and ARC will take care of memory management for you.